# Parse log entries with least possible overhead

Tags: go, parsing, logging

I have some log format with entries like this:
log_entry_no1 := "2021-11-03 7:7:51 hal9000 evil_app heartbeat C99 I am sorry Dave"
Those "fields" are separated by space except the last one called message which is just log data and can contain spaces.

My question is. Is there better way to process those entries without first splitting whole sentence and then join'ing that last part (message) with less overhead using go?

```
        type LogData struct {
            d        Date   // yyyy-mm-dd Mandatory
            t        Time   // hh:mm:ss Mandatory
            hostname string // Mandatory
            app_id   string // Mandatory
            etype    string // enum based string Mandatory
            level    string // Optional base on etype
            message  string // Mandatory
        }

        log_fields := strings.Split(log_entry_no1, " ")
        var log_data = LogData{}
        log_data.d = parseTime(log_entry_no1[0])
        log_data.t = parseTime(log_entry_no1[1])
        //...
        if log_fields[4] == "heartbeat" {
            log_data.level = log_fields[5]
            log_data.message = strings.Join(log_fields[6:], " ")
        } else {
            log_data.message = strings.Join(log_fields[5:], " ")
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you could just find spaces and slice the line. Although performance-wise it'll be similar (with less garbage).

Comment: What icza said: just find the last space before the tail (message) part and parse the part before that character (by first "slicing" it off the source `string` using the `[]` operator). Finding the Nth space character amounts to a simple `for` loop with a count or a seres of calls to `strings.Index` on a series of subslices with the starting character moving towards the end of the string; the `for` loop is way simpler).

Comment: [strings.SplitN](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#SplitN)

Answer (score 0):

Use strings.SplitN.

```
func SplitN(s, sep string, n int) []string
```

The docs say if n is greater than zero: it returns at most n substrings; the last substring will be the unsplit remainder.